# Setting date as getdate() for all the duplicates from tables and setting the date as null for the top 1 record

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-update

I have a table which as a bunch of duplicate records for come id's. My requirement is to update and set the date column as getdate() for all the records but for the top 1 in record in the duplicates (original record) I have to set the date column as null.

I cme up with the cte and update statements but they are updating all the records in the table but I need to set the date column for  top 1 record to null.

```
                                ;WITH CTE_Duplicate (application_ID, CW_Deferred_ID, DuplicateCount)
            AS (
                     SELECT application_ID, CW_Deferred_ID,Row_number()
                OVER ( PARTITION BY application_ID, CW_Deferred_ID ORDER BY application_ID) AS DuplicateCount
        FROM  dbo.Application_Refinance)


UPDATE dbo.Application_Refinance 
SET Inactive_Date = GETDATE()
               , Update_User = '13617'
       ,Update_Date = GETDATE()
FROM   CTE_Duplicate 
WHERE DuplicateCount > 1 and inactive_date  is NULL
```

I need to add some condition so that for all the duplicates records the update statement will set the date as getdate and for the top 1 record I need to set as null.

```
            ;WITH CTE_Duplicate (application_ID, CW_Deferred_ID, RowNumber)
            AS (
                     SELECT application_ID, CW_Deferred_ID,Row_number()
                OVER ( PARTITION BY application_ID, CW_Deferred_ID, CTE_Duplicate.RowNumber ORDER BY application_ID) AS Duplicate
        FROM  dbo.Application_Refinance)


UPDATE dbo.Application_Refinance 
SET Inactive_Date = CASE WHEN CTE_Duplicate.RowNumber = 1 
                         THEN NULL
                         else GETDATE()
                         end
               , Update_User = '13617'
       ,Update_Date = GETDATE()
FROM   CTE_Duplicate 
WHERE CTE_Duplicate.RowNumber > 1
```

when I tried this I am getting this error

The multi-part identifier "CTE_Duplicate.RowNumber" could not be bound.

When I just run the select part..

```
SELECT application_ID, CW_Deferred_ID, Inactive_date, Update_date, Update_user
                     ,Row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY application_ID, CW_Deferred_ID ORDER BY application_ID) AS RowNum
        FROM  dbo.Application_Refinance
```

id: 112979
XXX:753-0514763
Inactive_Date: 2016-12-29 12:22:54.533
update_Date: 2016-12-29 12:22:54.533
RowNum: 1

id: 112979
XXX:753-0514763 
Inactive_Date: 2016-12-29 12:22:54.533
Update_Date: 2016-12-29 12:22:54.533
RowNum:2

id: 112979
XXX:753-0514763 
Inactive_Date: 2016-12-29 12:22:54.533
Update_Date: 2016-12-29 12:22:54.533
RowNum:3

now I would like to set row= 1 as Null and row = 2 and row=3 and so on as getdate() where id has rowcount >1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH CTE_Duplicate 
            AS (
                     SELECT application_ID, CW_Deferred_ID, Inactive_date, Update_date, Update_user,
                     ,Row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY application_ID, CW_Deferred_ID, ORDER BY application_ID) AS RowNum
        FROM  dbo.Application_Refinance)
UPDATE CTE_Duplicate
SET Inactive_Date = CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 
                         THEN NULL
                         else GETDATE()
                         end
               , Update_User = '13617'
       ,Update_Date = GETDATE()
FROM   CTE_Duplicate 
WHERE Inactive_date IS NULL;
```

Comment: there is a date column in the table, for all the duplicate records I have to set the date as getdate() but for the top1 record in those duplicates i have to set as null. I hope this will clear you what I want. Thanks

Comment: OK. Then you can apply the above statement for that date column. Problem solved.

Comment: I editted the question with the error what I am getting can you please fix it for me please

Comment: Its is saying invalid column name ' Inactive_Date'

Comment: @kris Try again

Comment: Try running just the SELECT in the CTE and see if you have data to update. Otherwise, modify your question with test data and expected result.

Comment: Edited the questioned and the result set and what I want.

Comment: @kris Your original query have `inactive_date IS NULL` in the `WHERE` clause. And the result you showed all have data in the `inactive_date`. What do you think?

Comment: fixed the issue. Will post the solution for the problem. Thanks for your help.